# Plot sets in the complex plane

Tags: plotting, complex

I just want to know if there's a way to plot sets in the complex plane. For example
$$A=\{z\in \mathbb{C},z+e^{z}=0\},\\A=\{z\in \mathbb{C},\Re(z)+e^{z}\geq0\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do f.e.

```
fun = u + v I + E^(u + v I);

ContourPlot[{Re[fun] == 0, Im[fun] == 0}, {u, -6, 6}, {v, -6, 6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !! I don't know why parts of the graph has different colors ?

Comment: @user50618 Good question. `ContourPlot[{Re[fun] == 0, Im[fun] == 0}, {u, -6, 6}, {v, -6, 6}, PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}]`

Comment: There are two separate functions plotted: the blue lines are for Im[fun] == 0 and the orange lines are for Re[fun] == 0 (mouse over lines in Mathematica and look at the tooltips). Where the blue and orange lines intersect are the points for which fun == 0.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks !!!